# in R, How to create function to create multiple textinput widgets from list?

Tags: r, shiny

using R Shiny, I am trying to create function to create textinput or selectinput widget for all list elements
here is a example list

`xlist<-c("a","b","c")`

here is the textinput function

`textInput01 <- function(id, label = id) {textInput(id, label, value = "")}`

the ordinary solution and which is not efficient with large lists

`xlistCond<-list(textInput01("a"),textInput01("b"),textInput01("c"))`

the tried & not working code

`xlistCond<-mapply(textInput01,unlist(xlist))`

Comment: `xlist` is not a `list` - instead, it's a character vector. try something like `lapply(xlist, textInput01)` to give you a similar result as intended?

Comment: can't thank you enough

Comment: Dear @Ben another question please, if i have

`x<-list("a","b","c")`
`y<-list("e","f","g")`
`t<-list(x,y)`
`z<-list("O","p","q")`
`ll<-list(t,z)`

and i need to create nested tabPanel using function, in other word the tab selected automatically  create tabpanel for each element of the list and accordinly for the below level, as you see its a three levels list
i found some answers using ` do.call ` but it doesn't work with me.

Comment: this sounds like a new question - would recommend posting this as a separate question and including your shiny code

Comment: ok I will post it now , thank you

Comment: here is the question @Ben https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079852/in-r-shiny-how-to-automatically-or-based-on-function-tabpanel-given-we-have-3